# How to efficiently threshold a matrix in SIMULINK (remove noise)

Tags: math, matlab, simulink, opticalflow

I am doing some optical flow and I have a matrix of velocities, however I would like to discard (replace with zero) the entries which are below a certain threshold. Is there a convenient block that does this on a matrix signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be like:

```
> M= randn(100, 100);
> M(abs(M)< .1)= 0;
> sum(sum(0== M))
ans =  795
```

Comment: I know that you can use logical indexing in MATLAB, but what about SIMULINK? Is there a way without using an "embedded MATLAB" block?

Comment: What do you have against "embedded MATLAB" block?

Comment: @codenoob: perhaps your question could be instead something like `How to efficiently threshold a matrix in SIMULINK (remove noise), Note: without logical indexing in MATLAB` and you should also remove the `matlab` tag ;-). No, just kidding but what's the problem with `embedded MATLAB block`? Thanks

Comment: I thought embedded MATLAB was very slow to execute compared to native SIMULINK blocks? Is it not?

Comment: @codenoob: Do some tests to find out if the performance is sufficient ;-). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With Simulink, you can use a lookup table with method 'Interp-Extrap", Vector of inputs [0 th th (th+1)], table data [0 0 th (th+1)], with 'th' your threshold.
Between 0 and 'th', result is 0, upper that 'th', it's linear.

Answer (score 0):

if you can tolerate a few blocks (threshold of 1 shown):

[image]